# How can we delete a column from sql table by using code first approach in EF 6.0?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

By mistake I've added one column in my database Named as `doj` now if I want to drop that column from table using code first approach what should I do.

I've tried this things.

1- Removing the column definition from model.
2- Deleted Migration history.
3- Add-migration
4- Update database.

But still it is not reflecting in database? Where I made the mistake?

Comment: Did you delete the migration table in database?

Comment: Just remove the column in your model and delete the migration table ,if it doesn't work ,just remove the table that contains the column

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't need to delete migration history.

Just follow these steps

```
1: Remove properties from the model.
2: Run 'Enable-Migrations' in package manage console.
3: Next Run 'Add-Migration "MigrationsName"'. if any case it is showing 'The project  tesproject failed to build then build project again.
4: Now run 'Update-Database'
```

It will surly effect on your code. Go with [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

While Neeraj's answer is correct and in most cases works well, if that column has previous data in it, it will be removed from the index, but the data will still be there (and the column, for that matter).

To completely remove the column (and data in it), use the `DropColumn()` method. To accomplish this, create a new migration `add-migration unwantedColumnCleanup` and include the necessary code in the `up()` method, and then `update-database`.

```
namespace MyDB.Migrations
{
  using System;
  using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

  public partial class unwantedColumnCleanup : DbMigration
  {
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropColumn("Table", "Column");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It will return error when you want to publish your code to test/prod server since it has data in it. How to ignore that and force it to delete the column?

Answer (score 3):

You shoul do 
1-)Removing the column definition from model.
2-)Build your project
3-)add-migration
4-)update-database

You should not delete migration history.
Be carrefully when you were deleting column because you can  lost data in data in the table.

Comment: Verifying project build should have been a no-brainer though after seeing this, corrected a Resharper tool not being supported and then my build succeeded and was able to update.

Answer (score 1):

To Delete A Column after you have apply the migrations (update-database) in Asp.net core is quite simple. Follows the steps below:

1. Open your models folder and delete the specific property which is equivalent to the column you want to remove
2. Open your *Package Manager Console* and run *"Add-Migration anyMigrationName"*
3. Run **Update-Database**

Refresh your database and you will see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry actually I encountered with the same problem you just need to do is.
 
1 : Delete the property from the class you added for creating that column .
2 : Open Package Manager Console in Visual Studio. 
3 : You have already enabled migration so no need to run it again but for some reason if you are getting message for enabling migration just run **Enable-Migrations**
4 : Run **update-database -TargetMigration: "Migration"**

where migration in point 4 is the name of the migration you have added for adding your column.

Hope it will help you.