# EF unable to delete the columns in database code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a model like this:

```
public  class table1
{
    public Int64 Id { set; get; }
    public Int64 AutomotiveId { set; get; }
    public string Status { set; get; }
    public Int64 PlaqueCoded { set; get; }
    public Int64 ReferenceCount { set; get; }
}
```

After that I try to add another column like this:

```
 public  class table1
{
    public Int64 Id { set; get; }
    public Int64 AutomotiveId { set; get; }
    public string Status { set; get; }
    public Int64 PlaqueCoded { set; get; }
    public Int64 ReferenceCount { set; get; }
    public Int64 Price{ set; get; }
}
```

After some time I decided to remove the last column like this:

```
 public  class table1
{
    public Int64 Id { set; get; }
    public Int64 AutomotiveId { set; get; }
    public string Status { set; get; }
    public Int64 PlaqueCoded { set; get; }
    public Int64 ReferenceCount { set; get; }
}
```

As you can see I removed the `Price` from my model, but when I check my database, I can see the `Price` in the database.
Why can't EF delete this column?

My migration:

```
public class MigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public MigrationsConfiguration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What migration strategy are you using?

Comment: looks similar problem is already discussed here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985813/how-can-we-delete-a-column-from-sql-table-by-using-code-first-approach-in-ef-6-0]

Comment: @DonBoitnott i updated my post